# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' but its not wildcard in my server

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, ckeditor, firebase-storage

I have already changed my Access-Control-Allow-Origin != * but its still showing this error. It works on postman but not my website on localhost. I am trying to upload image into firebase storage

Error on client

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucketName.appspot.com/o/images' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Client code

```
simpleUpload: {
    // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
    uploadUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucketName.appspot.com/o/images',

    // Enable the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property.
    withCredentials: true,

    // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'CSFR-Token',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
```

Server firebase: cors.json

```
[
  {
    "origin": [
        "http://localhost.com:3000",
        "https://severName.web.app"
    ],
    "method": ["GET", "POST"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-CSRF-TOKEN"]
  }
]
```

Ran this on google cloud terminal

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://myservername.appspot.com
```

Comment: I think `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be set by your proxy or server and returned to the client. The browser then checks the response header. Could you show us your server/proxy configs/code?

Comment: hi thanks for the comment. stuck for 2 days. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i dont have any wildcard *. why is it saying i have a wildcard(*)? is the default Access-Control-Allow-Origin equal to wildcard (*)?

Comment: I don't know the answer yet but did you already go through this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors)? You may find your answer there. [This](https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f) may also be interesting.

Comment: i not sure if there is anyting wrong on the setting on my server because it works on postman but not on localhost browser.

Comment: What are your response headers?

Comment: here: "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]

Answer (score 0):

solve it by changing it like this.

```
simpleUpload: {
    // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
    uploadUrl: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucketName.appspot.com/o/images',

    // Enable the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property.
    withCredentials: false,

    // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
```